# Eclipse and MyEclipse Using Same project Different Settings

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I am working on a java project. The developer who started working on it is pretty firm on using myeclipse and I am pretty firm on using eclipse. Is there a way I can use the project settings that would not conflict with MyEclipse. When I open the project in Eclipse, I see a lot of myeclipse jar files for Java EE and what not. He's not using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to keep your project folders private and only share the source. Both of you cannot use the same project metadata.

Comment: This works by linking the source folders as an external link. However, I could not make it work so far since deployment to web folder is different for Eclipse and MyEclipse. When I removed Webcontent and replaced with webroot, eclipse could not build it. I will try making subfolders as a link rather than webcontent.      Even though I could not make it work, in theory it should work so I Am marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing metadata will cause both of you pain. And even more when upgrading to newer versions of eclipse and reading old projects.

Our solution was to switch to maven, and NOT having any metadata in source control repository. The m2e plugin then generates exactly the metadata you need when you import the maven projects in Eclipse.

An added benefit was that suddenly our projects worked with Netbeans and IntelliJ without any extra effort.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot switch to Maven because there is no desire from other side and he's a more senior developer so stuck with making it do with another solution.

Comment: In that case switch to myeclipse.

Comment: Might, if it was not so buggy and hard to use. Trying to bring it up on my machine takes about a minute and clicking on each page "jsf" takes another 20 secs while it parses and what not.. Prefer netbeans since it is less resource intensive than the MyEclipse and Eclipse

Comment: Too bad. If you cannot get the one you love, love the one you get.  I would, however, if I were you take a discussion with your common boss that you have a vendor lock in problem, which can be solved so people can use the IDE they prefer for a given task.  This might save the company money!